# Default Constructor error when using Spring 3.1 with RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-3, spring-annotations, spring-test

I have a custom argument resolver `SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver` that is working with Spring 3.0.7 but fails with Spring 3.1.2.  The stack trace and test-driver code appear below.
When I look at the stack trace, it appears that the `SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver.resolve( )` is not being invoked.  Instead, I see `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolve` in the stack trace.

Suggestions?

I have updated the java code to use `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (it was `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` from 3.0.7), however this stack trace is appearing when doing a runtime integration test:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xyz.security.web.SecurityRequestParameters.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.BeanUtils.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Class<T>) line: 104     
                 ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor).createAttribute(String, MethodParameter, WebDataBinderFactory, NativeWebRequest) line: 132          
                 ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(String, MethodParameter, WebDataBinderFactory, NativeWebRequest) line: 81       
                ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor).resolveArgument(MethodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory) line: 103             
                HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(MethodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory) line: 75     
                ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).getMethodArgumentValues(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 156     
                ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).invokeForRequest(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 117     
                ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 96           
                RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 617            
                RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 578         
                RequestMappingHandlerAdapter(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter).handle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Object) line: 80    
                SecuritySystemTestStartUp$1(DispatcherServlet).doDispatch(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 923                
                SecuritySystemTestStartUp$1(DispatcherServlet).doService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 852                
                SecuritySystemTestStartUp$1(FrameworkServlet).processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 882               
                SecuritySystemTestStartUp$1(FrameworkServlet).doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 789                
                SecuritySystemTestStartUp$1(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 637              
                SecuritySystemTestStartUp$1(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717                
                SecurityExternalAPISystemTest.testEncrypt() line: 86     
                 NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]        
                 NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available               
                 DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available       
                 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: not available       
                 FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall() line: 44             
                 FrameworkMethod$1(ReflectiveCallable).run() line: 15 
                 FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(Object, Object...) line: 41              
                 InvokeMethod.evaluate() line: 20            
                 RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate() line: 74         
                 RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate() line: 83            
                 SpringRepeat.evaluate() line: 72               
                 SecuritySpringJUnitRunner(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).runChild(FrameworkMethod, RunNotifier) line: 231           
                 SecuritySpringJUnitRunner(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner).runChild(Object, RunNotifier) line: 49         
                 ParentRunner$3.run() line: 193 
                 ParentRunner$1.schedule(Runnable) line: 52     
                 SecuritySpringJUnitRunner(ParentRunner<T>).runChildren(RunNotifier) line: 191            
                 ParentRunner<T>.access$000(ParentRunner, RunNotifier) line: 42           
                 ParentRunner$2.evaluate() line: 184       
                 RunBefores.evaluate() line: 28  
                 RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate() line: 61               
                 RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate() line: 71   
                 SecuritySpringJUnitRunner(ParentRunner<T>).run(RunNotifier) line: 236             
                 SecuritySpringJUnitRunner(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).run(RunNotifier) line: 174               
                 JUnit4TestClassReference(JUnit4TestReference).run(TestExecution) line: 50      
                 TestExecution.run(ITestReference[]) line: 38      
                 RemoteTestRunner.runTests(String[], String, TestExecution) line: 467    
                 RemoteTestRunner.runTests(TestExecution) line: 683   
                 RemoteTestRunner.run() line: 390           
                 RemoteTestRunner.main(String[]) line: 197
```

The test-driver code in SecuritySystemTestStartUp is annotated with @ContextConfiguration:

```
 @RunWith(SecuritySpringJUnitRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(loader = MockServletContextWebContextLoader.class,
         locations = { "classpath:/spring-system-test.xml" })
 public abstract class SecuritySystemTestStartUp
 {
     private static DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

     ...     
     public static DispatcherServlet getDispatcherServlet()
     {
         try
         {
             if (dispatcherServlet == null)
             {
                 final GenericWebApplicationContext context = new GenericWebApplicationContext();

                 context.setParent(MockServletContextWebContextLoader.getInstance());
                 context.refresh();

                 dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
                 dispatcherServlet.init(new MockServletConfig());
             }
         }
         catch (final Exception ex)
         ...
         return dispatcherServlet;
     }
 }
```

The argument resolver (compatible with Spring 3.0.7) is used in postProcessAfterInitialization.  A code-excerpt for the argument resolver appears below.

> public class AnnotationMethodHandlerBeanPostProcessor extends InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
>   {
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> public AnnotationMethodHandlerBeanPostProcessor(final SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver resolver)
> {
>     super();
>     _resolver = resolver;
> }
>
> @Override
> public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName)
> {
>      if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerAdapter)
>     {
>         final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean;
>         final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters =
>             adapter.getMessageConverters();
>
>         converters.add(new BinaryMessageConverter());
>         List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> customArgumentResolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>();
>         customArgumentResolvers.add(_resolver);
>
>         adapter.setCustomArgumentResolvers(customArgumentResolvers);
>         adapter.setMessageConverters(adapter.getMessageConverters());
>     }
>
>     return super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
> }
>
> ...
> ```
>
> }

and specified in the Spring Configuration as ...

> ```
> <bean id="SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver"
>     class="xyz.security.web.SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver">
>     <constructor-arg ref="CredentialsManager" />
>     <constructor-arg ref="TokenService" />
> </bean>
>
> <!-- A bean post-processor that registers the SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver. -->
> <bean class="xyz.security.web.AnnotationMethodHandlerBeanPostProcessor">
>     <constructor-arg index="0" ref="SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver" />
> </bean>
> ```

The flow of the arguments resolver is as follows:

> @Component
>   public class SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver
>   {
>       @Autowired  // implicitly autowired (not in xml)
>       private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
>
> ```
> private final CredentialsManager _credentialsManager;
> private final TokenService _tokenService;
>
> private RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = null;
>
> /* For the component scan... */
> SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver()
> {
>     this(null, null);
> }
>
> public SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver(final CredentialsManager credentialsManager,
>         final TokenService tokenService)
> {
>     super();
>     _credentialsManager = credentialsManager;
>     _tokenService = tokenService;
> }
>
> public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
>         NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception
> {
>
>     if (parameter != null && SecurityRequestParameters.class.equals(parameter.getParameterType()))
>     {
>         String productName = webRequest.getHeader(HttpHeader.PRODUCT_CONTAINER_HEADER.value());
>
>         ...
>
>         return new SecurityRequestParameters(credentials, contentType, acceptType, dataEncoding,
>                 sessionIdentifier, remoteIpAddress, securityProductName);
>     }
>     return new Object();
> }
>
> public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter)
> {
>     return getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor().supportsParameter(parameter);
> }
>
> private RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor()
> {
>     if (requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor == null)
>     {
>         List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters =
>                 requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getMessageConverters();
>         requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(messageConverters);
>     }
>     return requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor;
> }
> ```
>
> }

And lastly ... here is the annotation-driven tag from the Spring configuration

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
      <bean class="com.trgr.cobalt.security.web.SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Can you please show how you have registered the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver with Spring mvc and the code for the ArgumentResolver also

Comment: Biju, I updated the description to include part of the Spring configuration (xml) and most of the ArgumentResolver.

Comment: The annotation driven tag is...   

 <mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
   <bean class="com.trgr.cobalt.security.web.SecurityRequestParametersArgumentResolver"></bean>
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>

Comment: I see that your supports method in turn depends on `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.supports()..which requires the attribute to be annotated with `@RequestBody`..can you confirm that your parameter has `@RequestBody` annotation?

Comment: Here is the parameter annotation.  The "resolve" should be applied to ParamResolver, rather than the RequestBody.

> \@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/encrypt/{key}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
> \@ResponseBody
> public CryptographicResource createEncryptResource(\@ParamResolver final SecurityRequestParameters parameters,
>             \@PathVariable("key") final String key, \@RequestBody final byte[] requestPayload)
>     {
>         ...
>         
>         return _securityService.encrypt(parameters, key, request);
>     }

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments I think you will have to change your `supportsParameter` to the following:

```
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter)
{
    return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(ParamResolver.class)!=null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made this change but it did not fix the issue [yet, anyway :-) ]